# Flutter hot restart crashes - suspecting Firebase Firestore issue

Tags: flutter, firebase, crash

I'm experiencing an issue where performing a **hot restart** in my Flutter app results in a **crash** - 'Lost connection to device'. I suspect it might be related to Firebase Firestore, but I'm not sure. I've checked the Flutter logs, and they don't provide sufficient information to identify the problem. Hot reload works fine.

- Device: physical Pixel 6a running Android 14
- Flutter 3.17.0-1.0.pre.3 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

  Framework • revision 12b47270b7 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-11-27 17:21:11 -0600

  Engine • revision dff66925dc

  Tools • Dart 3.3.0 (build 3.3.0-91.0.dev) • DevTools 2.29.0
- Firebase package version:

  ```
    cloud_firestore: ^4.13.3
  ```

  ```
    firebase_core: ^2.24.0
  ```

Here are logs from running flutter run --verbose and performing hot restart (shift + r):

```
Performing hot restart...
```

```
Updating assets
```

```
Manifest contained wildcard assets. Inserting missing file into build graph to force rerun. For more information, see #56466.
```

```
Scanned through 716 files in 8ms
```

```
Syncing files to device Pixel 6a...
```

```
<- reset
```

```
Compiling Dart to kernel with 0 updated files
```

```
Processing bundle.
```

```
<- recompile package:smart_birthday_calendar/main.dart 5b74e0c6-0be6-4b71-bec8-5ffff40de1d5
```

```
<- 5b74e0c6-0be6-4b71-bec8-5ffff40de1d5
```

```
Bundle processing done.
```

```
Updating files.
```

```
Service protocol connection closed.
```

```
Lost connection to device.
```

```
DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device (file:///data/user/0/com.example.smart_birthday_calendar/code_cache/Smart-Birthday-CalendarPPXNXV/Smart-Birthday-Calendar/)
```

```
Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after 0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
```

```
"flutter run" took 141,875ms.
```

```
ensureAnalyticsSent: 80ms
```

```
Running 1 shutdown hook
```

```
Shutdown hooks complete
```

```
Exiting with code 0
```